# How to subtract a value in one table from a value in a different table based on common ID in calculation field

Tags: relationship, calculation

I'm trying to subtract a value in one field from a value in another table, depending on ID number using Filemaker Pro 19.x. I thought I'd done this before without any problems but now it isn't working and I don't know why.

First, I want to do this in a calculation field, not in a script. I don't understand scripting at all and use it only when there is no alternative. In this case, I think a calculation field should work.

I have 2 tables, I'll call them "Data" and "Categories"
Both tables have the field "CID" "Category ID".
The CID fields in both tables are linked in the Relationship Editor
The Data table has a field "Product ID"
The Categories table has several fields related to products. Two of those are "MIN PID" and "MAX PID". These are the minimum and maximum product ID numbers.
Product IDs are assigned in ranges. If it is within a certain range, it has to belong to a certain category. These categories have CID numbers.

To assign the CID number to the products listed on the Data table, I did run a script that essentially recreated all the data within the Categories table. It was inefficient (in my eyes) because the data was sitting right there in the table. I couldn't figure out how to reference it, so I gave up and ran the script instead. The other problem is that if the CID ever changes for a product, I have to rerun the script (or someone else, who might not know about the script)

That said, I now have the correct CID assigned for all 62 product categories. What I want to do now is to use the CID MIN and CID MAX values (among others) in calculation fields in the Data table.

For instance, if the product ID is "45,001", it belongs to the Category "16", which has a MIN value of "30,000" and a MAX value of "50,000". I want to subtract the "30,000" from the "45,001", (PID - CID MIN) to return the result "15,001". This allows me to locate a product within the category. Instead of being "Product 45,001", it will be "Product 16.15001".

The calculation I tried is:
If (CID = CID::CID ; PID - CID::CID MIN)
The result is a huge group of records where this field is empty.
I also tried:
PID - CID::CID MIN
Again, no results.
Both tables have the field "CID"
The two CID fields are linked in the relationship editor.

I have tried this with a test file and it works perfectly. It does not work in the database I am working within.

What am I doing wrong?